# Best functional way of handling conditional flows

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I have an Option of String which may be empty too. I have written following code to handle different branches of flow:

```
input match {
   case Some(val) => {
     val match {
        case "sayHi" => "Hi"
        case "sayHello" => "Hello"
        case _ => extractFromAnotherInput
     }
   }
   None => extractFromAnotherInput
}

private def extractFromAnotherInput = {
 anotherInput match {
   case a => ....
   case b => ....
 }
}
```

Is this a good way of handling code branches in a functional language or it can be done in a better way?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with _"good"_ and _"better"_.; it also depends on what exactly you do on each branch. But in general, IMHO, using pattern matching is OK. - However, you may want to check to higher order combinators like `filter` and `map`  to reduce a bit of repetition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to nest the matches:

```
input match {
   case Some("sayHi") => "Hi"
   case Some("sayHello") => "Hello"
   case _ => extractFromAnotherInput
}
```

You can also combine this input with "another", and "strip" he option before doing the match:

```
input.getOrElse(anotherInput) match {
   case "sayHi" => "Hi"
   case "sayHello" => "Hello"
   case a => ... 
   case b => ...
}
```

Comment: In second solution, if input has some valid value other than  "sayHi" and "sayHello", would it still work?

Answer (score 2):

I would go with Dima's solution. Or if you want to use some method on `Option`:

```
input.collect{
  case "sayHi" => "Hi"
  case "sayHello" => "Hello"
}
.getOrElse(extractAnotherInput)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of style: I personally dislike pattern-matching on `Option`, but that's idiosyncratic (I also may be the only Scala programmer who generally dislikes the `for` notation, but that's neither here nor there).

I'd express that as

```
input.flatMap { v =>
  v match {
    case "sayHi" => Some("Hi")
    case "sayHello" => Some("Hello")
    case _ => None
  }
}.getOrElse(extractAnotherInput)
```

If overfitting to this example (exploiting the fact that I can uniformly transform `sayHi` and `sayHello`)

```
input.filter(v => v == "sayHi" || v == "sayHello")
  .map(_.drop(3))
  .getOrElse(extractAnotherInput)
```

Comment: Ach, my mental compiler is on holiday :)

Comment: You could also use `input.collect{case "sayHi" => "Hi"; case "sayHello" => "Hello"}.getOrElse(extractAnotherInput)`. I find this cleaner, without the `flatMap`.

Answer (score 1):

Just because, I would like to propose an alternative to Levi's answer; just to remark this is more of a matter of opinion.

```scala
input.filter(_.nonEmpty).fold(ifEmpty = extractAnotherInput) {
  case "sayHi" => "Hi"
  case "sayHello" => "Hello"
}
```